# Laravel Eloquent how to create UNIQUE constraint with duplicate NULLs

Tags: sql-server, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm usinq Laravel 5 with MS Sql Server 2014.
I want to create a unique constraint but it should allow multiple null values.

Here is code I'm using. Where 'passport_no' has to be unique if not null.

```
Schema::create('UserProfile', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('userprofile_id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('passport_no', 50)->unique()->nullable();

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Comment: As far as I know, MS SQL-Server does not support this out of the box, however, it seems like you can [work around it](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2008/unique-constraint-multiple-nulls) since version 2008. So you could probably just set it manually with `DB::raw(...);` in the `up()`-function in your migration.

Comment: I don't know if the Laravel framework supports filtered indexes directly but in T-SQL, you can create a unique filtered index: `CREATE INDEX UQ_UserProfile_passport_no ON dbo.UserProfile(passport_no) WHERE passport_no IS NOT NULL`.  You could also create a view on the table with 'WHERE passport_no IS NOT NULL` and create a unique index on the view.

Answer (score 6):

This is an ancient question, but sill needs answering. As stated above, SQL Server from 2008, including Azure SQL, supports a special index that will work around it. In your database migration you can check the driver used and substitute the database builder standard SQL with an MSSQL-specific statement.

This migration example is for Laravel 5+, and creates a users table with a unique, but nullable, `api_token` column:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->string('name', 100)->nullable()->default(null);
        // etc.

        $table->string('api_token', 80)->nullable()->default(null);

        if (DB::getDriverName() !== 'sqlsrv') {
            $table->unique('api_token', 'users_api_token_unique');
        }
    });

    if (DB::getDriverName() === 'sqlsrv') {
        DB::statement('CREATE UNIQUE INDEX users_api_token_unique'
           . ' ON users (api_token)'
           . ' WHERE api_token IS NOT NULL');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use a unique Index and in its filter set your condition like

```
passport_no is not null
```

in this way you can solve your problem